# Somar resultados de Divs Dinâmicas - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, tenho um botão que gera novas divs de forma dinâmica, o id dessas divs ficam "div+count", ou seja, são geradas divs com os ids [div0, div1, div2, ...]. eu gostaria de somar o que tem nessas divs.

div0 = 2
div1 = 2
div3 = 2

divResultadoTotal = 6

As divs podem ser geradas e editadas a qualquer momento. Preciso somar as mesmas de forma dinâmica coletando as mesmas pelos ids.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2):

Tente usar este código:

```
function somarDivs() {
  let total = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    let valorDiv = document.getElementById(`div${i}`).innerHTML;
    total += parseInt(valorDiv);
  }
  document.getElementById('divResultadoTotal').innerHTML = total;
}
```